# Artisan commands possibly being cached or running wrong command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a strange issue since I've moved my website to a new server. The old server was running PHP 5.4, the new server PHP 5.6. I have over a dozen Artisan commands in Laravel 4.2 that run via cron at different intervals. Occasionally, it will run the wrong command. I don't know how often it happens since most don't give any output, but occasionally I'll get an error notification from Command Y, but the command that was run was Command M. `apc.enable_cli` and `opcache.enable_cli` are set to off. Are there any other caching settings I should be looking at, or a different setting?

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: Use `composer dump-autoload`. This will definitely solve your issue.

Comment: @Manish I'll try that.

Comment: @meda, I think that's only for the web, and it would be annoying and counter productive to run that command a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it was a programming error, and an incomplete understanding of how Artisan works.

When an artisan command is run, Artisan loads up all of the Artisan command classes, which runs the __construct method on each one. It will then fire the correct command. My issue was that I had some code in Command Y's __construct() method that would randomly fail. I moved that code to the fire() method so it will only run when that particular command is called. I verified this by using `Log::debug("Running " . implode(' ', $_SERVER['argv']) . " from " . __CLASS__);` in the __construct method, and then moving that line to the fire method.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do:

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: The composer dumpautoload may have done it, which makes me feel silly. It doesn't happen all the time, so I'll check back in in a day or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with both commands, the same thing happens.