# php artisan migrate runs console commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

PHP Artisan/Laravel question here. I have a couple command scripts in App/Console/Commands, which I basically use as scripts to execute from the cli when I wish.

Oddly, running `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/main` seems to execute those commands. I created the commands after my schema, which is why I'm just running into the problem now. I'm running migrations on a new server for the first time, and since none of the tables exist that are called in the first command script, the migrate command chokes and says the tables don't exist. However, I don't want migrate to run any of these other commands when I'm trying to run migrations - that doesn't make sense to me. I'm thinking there's a way to stop this by updating my Kernal.php file that's also in the Commands folder, but I'm not sure how. Assuming there's something going on here with PHP Artisan that I don't fully understand, but can't seem to find an answer to. Thanks!

Comment: When Artisan runs, it will automatically load all of the commands registered. Make sure you remove anything unnecessary from the `__construct()` functions of all of the commands, and you shouldn't have an issue. See my learning process at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440615/artisan-commands-possibly-being-cached-or-running-wrong-command

Comment: Just ran into this issue; one of my Artisan commands was calling `Model::where(...)` in `__construct()`, which, when copied to a fresh install and running `php artisan migrate` threw the error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ... doesn't exist`. Simple solution is to move logic into a separate function, like `public function constructAdditional()` and call that where required in `public function handle(){ $this->constructAdditiona(); ... }`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any possible solutions ?